# Trying to plot graph in python causes error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the trend of crimes so I read data from Mongo DB and then process it in python:

reader.py

```
def read_from_csv_and_push_to_db(path):
    data = pd.read_csv(path)
    payload = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
    db_connection.write_to_mongo('Course', 'crimes', payload)

def read_from_csv_and_push_to_db(path):
    data = pd.read_csv(path)
    payload = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
    db_connection.write_to_mongo('Course', 'crimes', payload)


def process_data(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df.head(5))
    df['time_hour'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: arrow.get(x, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A").format("HH"))
    df['month'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: arrow.get(x, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A").format("MM"))
    df['day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: arrow.get(x, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A").format("DD"))
    df['year'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: arrow.get(x, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A").format("YYYY"))
    return df

# read from mongo and processing 
data = db_connection.read_from_mongo('Course', 'crimes', 1000)
df_final = process_data(data)
```

Next, I use this df_final in `trends.py` which plots everything

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_trend_crimes_per_month():
    df_final.resample('M').size().plot(legend=False)
    plt.title('Number of crimes per month in US 2012-2017')
    plt.xlabel('Month')
    plt.ylabel('Number of crimes')
    plt.savefig('img/number_of_crimes.png', format='png')
```

Here is error:

```
  File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/trends.py", line 20, in <module>
  plot_trend_crimes_per_month()
  File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/trends.py", line 14, in plot_trend_crimes_per_month
  df_final.resample('M').size().plot(legend=False)
  File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8155, in resample
  base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1250, in resample
  return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/Users/ilya/PycharmProjects/coursework/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1380, in _get_resampler
  "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
  TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

I've tried to convert everything to datetime but in vain. 
The dataset looks like this

```
ID,Case Number,Date,Block,IUCR,Primary Type,Description,Location Description,Arrest,Domestic,Beat,District,Ward,Community Area,FBI Code,X Coordinate,Y Coordinate,Year,Updated On,Latitude,Longitude,Location
3,10508693,HZ250496,05/03/2016 11:40:00 PM,013XX S SAWYER AVE,0486,BATTERY,DOMESTIC BATTERY SIMPLE,APARTMENT,True,True,1022,10.0,24.0,29.0,08B,1154907.0,1893681.0,2016,05/10/2016 03:56:50 PM,41.864073157,-87.706818608,"(41.864073157, -87.706818608)"
89,10508695,HZ250409,05/03/2016 09:40:00 PM,061XX S DREXEL AVE,0486,BATTERY,DOMESTIC BATTERY SIMPLE,RESIDENCE,False,True,313,3.0,20.0,42.0,08B,1183066.0,1864330.0,2016,05/10/2016 03:56:50 PM,41.782921527,-87.60436317,"(41.782921527, -87.60436317)"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your error is `df_final.resample('M')...` You need a `datetime`-like index for that to work. Either set the index to whatever column is your `datetime` or specify `on=` in the resample.

Comment: @ALollz, so you mean to add  `resample(on='M')`?

Comment: No. I mean you first need to make sure your dates are stored as a `datetime`: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` and then you would specify `df.resample('M', on='Date')`. There is also no need to define all of those additional columns. One you convert to a `datetime` these are all readily available through the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors). The docs have a whole section on [date and time handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)